# Infinite series involving $\frac{1}{\sinh(an+b)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would like to know if anybody knows of a way to express the following infinite series

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sinh(a\,n+b)}
$$

with $a,b>0$ in a closed form, likely involving the $q-$digamma function.

I have attempted the following:

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sinh(a\,n+b)}&=2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{e^{a\,n+b}-e^{-a\,n-b}}=2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \frac{e^{-a\,n-b}}{1-e^{-2a\,n-2b}}\\
&=2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} \sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}e^{-a\,n-b-2a\,n\,j-2\,b\,j}\\
&=2\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} e^{-a\,n-b-2a\,n\,j-2\,b\,j}\\
&=-2\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{e^{-2 b j-b}}{1-e^{2 a j+a}}\,,
\end{align}

but now I can't evaluate the final sum. Any thoughts?

Comment: I think you want your final summation to be $\sum_{j=0}^{+\infty}\frac{2 e^{-2 b j-b}}{e^{2 a j+a}-1}.$

Comment: Thanks - It has been amended.